# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds when trying to add to list from string array

Tags: java, arrays, list, file, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having one problem that is preventing my entire code from working. It is having an array index out of bounds error, but it matches the file array perfectly, so I'm not sure what the problem is..

```
public void Menu() {
    prompt.welcomeMsg();
    prompt.nGramOptionMsg();
    String userInput = input.next();
    while (userInput.charAt(0) != 's' || userInput.charAt(0) != 'S') {
        if (userInput.charAt(0) == 'n' || userInput.charAt(0) == 'N') {
            prompt.nGramLengthMsg();
            int userIntut = input.nextInt();
            nGram = new NGram(userIntut);
            prompt.fileUpload();
            String userFilePut = input.next();
            FileOpener file = new FileOpener(userFilePut);
            String[] fileArray = file.openFile();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
                String[] splitedFileArray = fileArray[i].split("\\s+");
                list.add(splitedFileArray[i]);
            }
            String[] listToStringArray = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[0]);
            String[] nGrams = nGram.arrayToNGram(fileArray);
            for (int i = 0; i < nGrams.length; i++) {
                Word word;
                if (!hashMap.containsKey(nGrams[i])) {
                    word = new Word(nGrams[i], 1);
                    hashMap.put(word.getNGram(), word);
                } else {
                    Word tempWord = hashMap.remove(nGrams[i]);
                    tempWord.increaseAbsoluteFrequency();
                    hashMap.put(tempWord.getNGram(), tempWord);
                }

            }

            HashMapFiller fill = new HashMapFiller();
            fill.hashMap(hashMap);
            fill.print();

            prompt.goAgain();
        }
```

}

The problem occurs when the list.add is trying to add the splitedFileArray. I tried doing fileArray.length-1 but it had a similar error, except -1.

Comment: You should iterate the new array 'splitedFileArra' and then you can assign all part of splited array into list.
This line is wrong: list.add(splitedFileArray[i]); 'i' not splited array index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @dave is right.  When the program compiles and runs, but givens runtime exceptions or unexpected results, it's time for some debugging. Help yourself to these [free debugging tips](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) if you need some suggestions on how to get started.  And if you haven't yet familiarized yourself with your IDE's debugger, now is the perfect opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for this problem is that you are trying to access the array in following line. What actually happening in behind the scenes is that you actually try to access unknown sized array which is returned from the `split()` method. returned array size might be less than the defined index (in your case `i`).

```
list.add(splitedFileArray[i]);
```

You can resolve this problem as follows..

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
    String[] splitedFileArray = fileArray[i].split("\\s+");
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(splitedFileArray));
}
```

Hope this answer will help you to resolve your problem...